# Replica failed with error mongo db

Tags: replication, mongodb, sharding

I am running mongo sharded cluster with two replica set as shards.
One set is working fine but replica secondary on other replica set is not working. When ever i restart it it gives me this error and failed.

2014-09-04T08:16:16.634+0530 [rsSync] replSet initialSyncOplogApplication applied 1001 operations, synced to Sep  3 15:26:47:3d
2014-09-04T08:16:17.164+0530 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:12725 virt:2814759
2014-09-04T08:16:17.164+0530 [clientcursormon]  mapped (incl journal view):2813248
2014-09-04T08:16:17.164+0530 [clientcursormon]  connections:16
2014-09-04T08:16:17.164+0530 [clientcursormon]  replication threads:32
2014-09-04T08:16:21.454+0530 [repl writer worker 1] ERROR: exception:  :: caused by :: 56 An empty update path is not valid. on: { ts: Timestamp 1409738211000|67, h: -8833753959820233956, v: 2, op: "u", ns: "ibeat20140903.visitor", o2: { _id: ObjectId('54060caebc88dbf98cc57898') }, o: { $set: { : 20, AID-41575656: 17, count: 1938, pgAccessTime: 1409738211851 } } }
2014-09-04T08:16:21.454+0530 [repl writer worker 1] Fatal Assertion 16361
2014-09-04T08:16:21.454+0530 [repl writer worker 1]

***aborting after fassert() failure

I tried clearing the db folder and start replica to resync from start but still didn't work.

Comment: Which mongo version you running? can you share an rs.conf and rs.status?

Comment: Hi Antonis this happenend while we were upgrading to 2.6.4 rs.conf();
{
        "_id" : "firstset",
        "version" : 63560,
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "host" : "192.168.22.113:27017"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "host" : "192.168.26.60:27017",
                        "arbiterOnly" : true
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 3,
                        "host" : "192.168.33.143:27017"
                }
        ]
}

Comment: Seems that something went wrong with the upgrade: did you execute upgrade on SEC then promote it with rs.stepdown and then upgrade the other members?

Comment: Additionally are you able to dump the database?

Comment: Hi Antonis it wasn't upgrade failure it was due to one record in oplog that was empty field. When it was override system became good again.